# Backup postgreSQL database through ODBC (windows, .NET)

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, odbc

I'm trying to backup my database through ODBC with vb.net but can't find a way.
Some of many approaches:

```
        Try
            btCommand = New OdbcCommand("pg_dump '" + mydatabase + "' > 'all.sql'", mCon)
            'OR
            ' btCommand = New OdbcCommand("BACKUP DATABASE '" + mydatabase + "',  'all.sql'", mCon)
            btCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        End Try
```

But no one works.
Please advice on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pg_dump` is a command line executable, not a SQL command.

There are many different options for backing up a PostgreSQL database system.  You should probably read through [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/backup.html) to see which one is the best fit for you.

Comment: After reading, still can't find or don't understand usable way for backing up through odbc command. Any closer recommendation?

Comment: You could try to emulate what pg_dump does by running a lot COPY statements and such, but why not use one of the tools already written and available? Surely you have some way to access the database besides ODBC?

Comment: Yes, I can access (and backup) my database by few ways. I can also shell from my program to pg_dump.exe. But I am just curious if here becomes some totally programatic way covered by ODBC. Never mind if not. Thanks for helping!